# Is there any way to throw exception from MySQL to Node.js (mysql2-promise)?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a complex stored procedure (inserts, updates, etc...). The logic wrapped in transaction and if there is any issue I roll back.

Here is a simplified example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testing`(IN _recordID INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        SELECT @p2;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    
    START TRANSACTION;

    IF (EXISTS(SELECT user FROM tblData WHERE recordID = _recordID)) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'There is protected data';
    END IF

    DELETE FROM tblData WHERE recordID = _recordID
    COMMIT;
END
```

Technically the stored procedure will run successfully in any case (until server is available and table exists). **I want to throw error message from MySQL to Node.js server announcing that there was an exception.** I use `mysql2-promise` package on the application server.

Taylor made solution such as parsing returned rows is not an option since I'm looking for a robust solution for production system.